# No transparency in Bitmap when loading from MemoryStream

Tags: c#, bitmap, memorystream

When I am writing a `Bitmap` to a file and read from the file, I am getting the transparency correctly.

```cs
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(2, 2))
{
    Color col = Color.FromArgb(1, 2, 3, 4);
    bmp.SetPixel(0, 0, col);
    bmp.Save("J.bmp");
}

using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("J.bmp"))
{
    Color col = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0);
    // Value of col.A = 1. This is right.
}
```

But if I write the `Bitmap` to a `MemoryStream` and read from that `MemoryStream`, the transparency has been removed. All alpha values become `255`.

```cs
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(2, 2))
{
    Color col = Color.FromArgb(1, 2, 3, 4);
    bmp.SetPixel(0, 0, col);
    bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
}

using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms))
{
    Color col = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0);
    // Value of col.A = 255. Why? I am expecting 1 here.
}
```

I wish to save the `Bitmap` to a `MemoryStream` and read it back with transparency. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: There is no `ms.position=0` before `new Bitmap(ms)` call. Not sure if it is problem in this case, so comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line: `bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp)`. ImageFormat.Bmp does not support alpha values, you can change it to ImageFormat.Png for the same effect.

Comment: +1 to `.Png` suggestions. It is somewhat surprising that reading bitmap from stream actually does seek on the stream, but it seem that `ms.position=0` before `new Bitmap(ms)` when I expect one.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK BMP format doesn't support transparency. Check changing your format to, say, PNG on:

```
bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
```

You can however index a .bmp which will add a transparent colour in the 256th spot. Problem is, a lot of image requirements for bmp are 24 and 32 bit, and a transparent indexed image will only convert to 16 bit.